# uiscrollview and uibutton behaves transparent for touch events

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a custom subclass of UIView and a full screen UIButton with a background image on it as you can see in the image, 
on the right side, there is a UIView with a UIImageView on it and some other not important labels and buttons. The important part is, there are two scrollviews on that UIView and at the run time, i add UIButtons ( not small ones, 200 x 100 ) on those scrollviews with vertical scrolling enabled.
The situation is really very complex so i will write as items what happens in different conditions. In my application, there are 10 of these complete screens, on a custom subclass of UIView and i use UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll from one to other.I have a good reason not to use a scrollview for this. All the windows ( the below image, not UIWindow ) populates their content in a loop, so the running code is exact same for all of them and all of them are being created from the same .xib file. And the last information, the bigger UIButton that covers all the window has an action for touchupinside and the smaller buttons in scrollviews have their own touchupinside selectors.

- Some of my windows works perfectly, if i touch anywhere on the screen, the bigger buttons action is called, if i touch and drag, the scroll works and i navigate to the next / previous window, if i touch on smaller buttons in scrollviews, their actions fired and lastly i can perfectly scroll within those buttons.
- Some of my windows, when i try to scroll the scrollviews, the bigger windows pangesturerecognizer catchs this event not the small scrollviews, and if i touch the small button in that scroll view, the bigger buttons event is fired ( it pass all through uibutton > uiscrollview > uiimageview > uiview  to the uibutton at the button like they dont exist )
- if i replace the right container view some other position on the big uibutton, it randomly works well or not, sometimes one of the scrollviews works well and the other not.
- it has a consistent behaviour, if on a one position, it works, it allways works, and if it not, it never does.
- Again, all the views and subclasses have their userinteraction enabled yes, the opposite is already imposible because the behaviour changes only acording to position of container view on the big uibutton and also changes acording to big uibuttons background image.
- I've placed a touchesBegan method for just test purposes, when the touches does not work as expected, the event fired with touch.view is the container of the big button, even if i touch on a small button within the scrollviews.

I've spend two days already for that and no result.What can cause this behaviour ?

EDIT : After krumelur's comment I've changed my focus from configuration of those views to animation i give to the container views, and i've noticed that, the problem is about the animation, i'm adding the the code part that animates all ten windows and behaves like a custom scrollview. All windows have their custom layer class and when i catch pangesture recognizer i move windows on the screen with following code. items in that code is an array which holds layers of all the windows. The animation causes that strange situation but i couldnt figure out yet..

```
- (void)layoutSublayers {
[super layoutSublayers];

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

float angleDelta = 2 * M_PI / [items count];
float a = angle;

for (UIBaseLayer *l in items) {

    l.position = self.position;  

    CATransform3D translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(cosf(a)*(radius.x), 1.0, (sinf(a)*radius.y) - radius.y*1.0);

    float dailyAngle = (M_PI_2 - a);
    CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(dailyAngle, 0, 1.0, 0);
    CATransform3D t = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
    l.transform = t;

    a += angleDelta;
}
[CATransaction commit];}
```

http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/296/screenshot20111215at013.png

Comment: I don't want to frustrate you, but I'd say your question is way to complex and has too little info for an exhaustive answer. There are so many things that can go wrong that it is impossible to tell what the issue is. Could be incorrectly wired event handlers, z-order of your views mixed up, some property of UIScrollView not set correctly.
I suggest the basics of debugging: simplify it. Break it down. Remove unnecessary controls. Rethink your design. Start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've figured out that, even I send back views with `CATransform3DMakeTranslation` and `layer.zPosition` settings, touch events goes to views according to their frame position. The views that aren't currently even seen (overlayed by others) still catch touches. Writing just one line of code (`[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self]`) for the view that is currently on screen solved the problem.

For testing this and understanding what I'm talking about, I've made simple test application that has only two buttons on it.
The blue and yellow buttons.The blue button overlays the yellow button so you can only see the blue one at the beginning.
On the touch up inside code for the blue button, I just send it back with `buttons.layer.zPosition = -1`. After this, there is no visible part of the blue button remains on screen, instead I see just the yellow button now, but when I touch the yellow button (or I think I am touching it) still blue buttons touch up inside code runs.

I'm not sure if this is the desired logic but it does not seem reasonable to me.

As I mentioned above, writing `[blueButton.superview sendSubviewToBack:blueButton]` while setting its layers `zPosition` to -1 works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`bringSubviewToFront` did not work reliably on 5.0 (on 5.1 the hack was not needed)

I had to add a bigger transparrent `UIButton` around the button that behaved as if it was disabled to fix this on iOS prior to 5.1.